# @tf.function is slowing down training step

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using the following tf.function decorated training step:

```
@tf.function
def train_step(inputs, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        predictions = model([X, F], training=True)
        losses = [l_f(tf.expand_dims(labels[:,i], axis=-1), predictions[i]) for i, l_f in enumerate(loss_functions)]
    gradients = [tape.gradient(l, model.trainable_variables) for l in losses]
    for g in gradients:
        grads = [gg if gg is not None else tf.zeros_like(model.trainable_variables[i], dtype=tf.float32) for i, gg in enumerate(g)]
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables)
    del tape
    return losses


def weighted_loss(weights):
    @tf.function
    def loss_func(labels, predictions):
        min_class_filter = tfk.backend.greater(labels, 0.5)

        y_min = tf.boolean_mask(labels, min_class_filter)
        y_max = tf.boolean_mask(labels, tf.math.logical_not(min_class_filter))
        y_pred_min = tf.boolean_mask(predictions, min_class_filter)
        y_pred_max = tf.boolean_mask(predictions, tf.math.logical_not(min_class_filter))

        loss_min_class = tfk.backend.mean(tfk.backend.binary_crossentropy(y_min, y_pred_min))
        loss_max_class = tfk.backend.mean(tfk.backend.binary_crossentropy(y_max, y_pred_max))
        loss_all = tfk.backend.mean(tfk.backend.binary_crossentropy(labels, predictions))
        return weights[0]*loss_min_class + weights[1]*loss_max_class + weights[2]*loss_all
    return loss_func

loss_functions = [weighted_loss(w) for w in target_weights]
```

It's a little quirky, but basically, my network has multiple outputs, which means that there are cases where returning a gradient of None for certain weights is correct, so I am replacing those gradients with zero, and I'm calculating the loss at each of these outputs separately and then propagating each of them at each step.

When I run this as written, it takes an extremely long time (10min+) to run a single training step, and I see the following message in the logs:

```
E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:502] function_operator failed: Invalid argument: Input 0 of node model/LSTM_forward_0/zeros_like was passed int32 from model/LSTM_forward_0/StatefulPartitioned Call:9 incompatible with expected variant.
```

When I remove the @tf.function decorator, it runs in about 10% of the time, and I do not see this log warning.  Is this warning a red herring or does it legitimately point to an issue created by adding @tf.function?

Additional Details:

- TF 2.0
- GPU enabled and available
- CUDA 10.1
- GPU utilization 0% in both cases but that isn't caused by data-feed maxing the CPU throughput, as when I generate training data outside of the training loop, it's as good as instantaneous from TFRecords with sufficient prefetch and limited augmentation
- dtype of inputs, labels, gradients and all model.trainable_variables are all tf.float32

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, `tf.function` should not include any assignment to the graph vars for it to run smoothly.

In a training step, you are changing the weights of the model, thus violating this.

I'm not sure this is the reason, but you can try to leave `tf.function` only in the loss function, but not in the training step.

Comment: I don't think that can be right?  I know you aren't meant to create any new graph variables, but the whole point of the tape is to update the weights and I've seen similar forms all over the place - I think the issue may be with the persistent=True? [https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31938] see response from Aug 24.  Also that is what I tried in the original q, and GPU utilisation remains at 0% both ways --- although it is faster, it is still not as quick as I expect (i.e. much slower than (number of output branches)*(time for updating just one branch with persistant=False)).

Comment: I meant to say the whole point of the graph, not the whole point of the tape, tho I guess it's both, but only the first is an argument for saying you should be able to use tf.function.  Sorry - too late to edit!

Answer (score -1):

I have figured out how to fix it.  The issue was with overwriting None gradients, not with the persistent gradient tape.

```
@tf.function
def train_step(inputs, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        predictions = model([X, F], training=True)
        losses = [l_f(labels, predictions, i) for i, l_f in enumerate(loss_functions)]
    gradients = [tape.gradient(l, model.trainable_variables) for l in losses]
    for g in gradients:
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(g, model.trainable_variables)
    del tape
    return losses


def weighted_loss(weights):
    @tf.function
    def loss_func(labs, preds, i):
        labels = tf.expand_dims(labs[:,i], axis=-1)
        predictions = preds[i]
        min_class_filter = tfk.backend.greater(labels, 0.5)

        y_min = tf.boolean_mask(labels, min_class_filter)
        y_max = tf.boolean_mask(labels, tf.math.logical_not(min_class_filter))
        y_pred_min = tf.boolean_mask(predictions, min_class_filter)
        y_pred_max = tf.boolean_mask(predictions, tf.math.logical_not(min_class_filter))

        loss_min_class = tfk.backend.mean(tfk.backend.binary_crossentropy(y_min, y_pred_min))
        loss_max_class = tfk.backend.mean(tfk.backend.binary_crossentropy(y_max, y_pred_max))
        loss_all = tfk.backend.mean(tfk.backend.binary_crossentropy(labels, predictions))
        return weights[0]*loss_min_class + weights[1]*loss_max_class + weights[2]*loss_all
    return loss_func

loss_functions = [weighted_loss(w) for w in target_weights]
```

By passing all outputs and all labels into the loss function (even if I ignore a bunch of them) the tape will return an appropriate gradient (0) for all branches, not just the ones in focus for that particular loss.